# Asp.Net UpdatePanel in Gridview Jquery DatePicker

Tags: asp.net, jquery, updatepanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="asd" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvUpdate" runat="server">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DATE">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DATE","{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DATE","{0:dd.MM.yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </ContentTemplate>
```

i want jquery datepicker for "txtDate" how to make ?

Thank you...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most simple way is to place a class on your Date Text box, and just use jQuery to add the datepicker...

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" CssClass="clDate" 
  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DATE","{0:dd.MM.yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

and the javascript for init this is: `$(".clDate").datepicker();` but the update panel is need again initialization after the Update, so the final code will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   // if you use jQuery, you can load them when dom is read.
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
       prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
       prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

       // Place here the first init of the DatePicker
       $(".clDate").datepicker();
    });        

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
       // make unbind to avoid memory leaks.
       $(".clDate").unbind();
    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
       // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init the DatePicker
       $(".clDate").datepicker();
    }
</script>
```

Update:About the Sys. -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx

Comment: @Aristos Error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined pls help me

Comment: @oraclee do you have place the ScriptManager ? (because of your update panel you need to have it)

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"> </asp:ScriptManager> not work Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined

Comment: @oraclee you need to place the Sys. after the scriptManager !!!, or make it load when page load. See the example here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx

Comment: This works great in an update panel on it's own, but how do I get it to work in a detailsview inside an update panel?

Comment: The same way, this is working even if it is inside a detailsview. The updatePanel just need the EndRequest to reinitialize it.

Comment: @Aristos - Great explanation, saved the same problem I had. Works perfectly, and well explained :) Thanks!