# jQuery and ASP.NET UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm using the code below to toggle a few different elements on the push of a arrow button. How come this code won't work if I put it inside an ASP.net UpdatePanel?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".togglerElement").click(function () {
    var target = $(this).attr("id");
    ToggleTest(target);
});

function ToggleTest(target) {
    var container = "#" + target + "Container";
    var arrowUp = "#" + target + "ArrowUp";
    var arrowDown = "#" + target + "ArrowDown";

    $(container).slideToggle("fast");
    $(arrowUp).toggle();
    $(arrowDown).toggle();
}
```

});

Comment: So what does that mean? Why does it stop working?

Comment: actually ajax update panel will not work with jquery it's a very known problem you have to apply any fix for using that

Comment: So I'll have to do the toggle using Ajax then, huh? Thanks for the input!

Comment: welcome i have posted some links below may be that can help you

Comment: The UpdatePanel have custom functions that trigger on updates. Check this answer and see how this work and adjust your code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341623/asp-net-updatepanel-in-gridview-jquery-datepicker/3341741#3341741

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".togglerElement").live('click',function () {
    var target = $(this).attr("id");
    ToggleTest(target);
});

function ToggleTest(target) {
    var container = "#" + target + "Container";
    var arrowUp = "#" + target + "ArrowUp";
    var arrowDown = "#" + target + "ArrowDown";

    $(container).slideToggle("fast");
    $(arrowUp).toggle();
    $(arrowDown).toggle();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

these are some useful links

[Jquery Forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/asp-net-update-panel)

[Jquery and ajax update panel](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article471-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-updatepanel.aspx)

[One More](http://www.daharsh.net/tech/2008/01/aspnet-updatepanel-ajax-and-jquery.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `pageLoad` method in javascript code, and call your jQuery function inside of that function. And you can't use `click`. You need to use `on` if `.togglerElement` is inside of updatepanel.

for example:

```
function pageLoad(){

 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("body").on('click','.togglerElement',function(){
      var target = $(this).attr("id");
      ToggleTest(target);
   });
 });
}

function ToggleTest(target) {
    var container = "#" + target + "Container";
    var arrowUp = "#" + target + "ArrowUp";
    var arrowDown = "#" + target + "ArrowDown";
    $(container).slideToggle("fast");
    $(arrowUp).toggle();
    $(arrowDown).toggle();
}
```