# Validation plugin is not working in update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an update panel and inside the panel text boxes and buttons are available. Now I am using the jQuery Validation plugin, but the validation plugin is not working when it is used in the update panel.

For example:

```
function GetAddressTargetList() {
    var objArray = new Array();
    var objAddressElement = new Object();

    objAddressElement = new Object();
    objAddressElement.Id = "ddlAccType"; 
    objAddressElement.Rules = "required";
    objAddressElement.TargetControlType = "select";
    objArray[objArray.length] = objAddressElement;
    objAddressElement = new Object();
}
```

and in the page level (.aspx)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetAddressTargetList();
});

function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    // To load the tooltip in update panel
    if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
        GetAddressTargetList();
    }
}
```

How can I get the validation when I am using the update panel working?

Comment: Similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341623/asp-net-updatepanel-in-gridview-jquery-datepicker/3341741#3341741

Comment: initially tried with the above link mentioned, but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you have forget to initilize the `pageLoad`

Add this on your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoaded);
});

function PageLoaded(sender, args) {
    GetAddressTargetList();
}
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523(VS.100).aspx

### Update

I have update **the pageLoad to PageLoaded**, to avoid conflict after the comment of the **rs**. In my opinion the UpdatePanel have a custom way to handle the events and what we try here is to trigger the event on javascript after the UpdatePanel Updates the content.

Comment: I dont think this is correct answer, pageLoad and pageUnload are reserved names in ajax. And if we use them we dont have to bind explicit handler for them. Use different name for function if using explicit bind. Src - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417(v=vs.100).aspx [search pageLoad]

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of document.ready, ajax pageLoad is called after every partial postbacks

```
function pageLoad() { 
    GetAddressTargetList();
  }
```