# Execute javascript after a partial postback of an updatepanel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page that add tree file script to it .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
```

I have a updatepanel with a dropdownlist. When run SelectedIndexChanged event (partial postback of an updatepanel), don't execute javascript .

Comment: Here is how you do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341623/asp-net-updatepanel-in-gridview-jquery-datepicker/3341741#3341741

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the `pageLoad` function:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
  InitialiseSettings();
}

function InitialiseSettings(){
    // replace your DOM Loaded settings here. 
    // If you already have document.ready event, 
    // just take the function part and replace here. 
    // Not with document.ready 
    $(element).slideUp(1000, method, callback});

    $(element).slideUp({
                   duration: 1000, 
                   easing: method, 
                   complete: callback});
}
```

Or, try adding an "end request" event handler with `.add_endRequest()`:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(InitialiseSettings)
```

---

**Edit:**

It would be a better idea for you to move your code from `document.ready` into `InitialiseSettings()`, and to then register it as a **[`pageLoaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** event handler.

**Code Example**

```js
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitialiseSettings)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but to initialization easing in InitialiseSettings .

Comment: Thanks, I should use this: `$(document).ready(function () {Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(InitialiseSettings)  function InitialiseSettings() {
            //easing, other initialization goes here
        }  })
 </script>`

Comment: @Niloo, No man no. Please share more code. Do you have document.ready block in your page? Where do you configure those easing and all.

Comment: I add my function with document.ready, it is work for me ... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is this compatible on all browsers?

Comment: @Pierre, yes it is compatible

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll stick with the add_endRequest as using the add_pageLoaded event makes the ScriptResource.axd throw the following error: Uncaught Sys.ArgumentNullException: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: panelsCreated[1]

Answer (score 24):

To run your javascript in full and partial postbacks, put your javascript code into javascript pageLoad() function.

```
function pageLoad()
{
   //your javascript code
}
```

Example:

```
function pageLoad() {

    $(':submit').click(function () {
        CommodityArray();
    });
    $('#btn_image').click(function () {
       CommodityArray();
    });
    $(".repHeader").disableSelection();

    CommodityArray();
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: @Aristos :: Do you mean that, this does not work with update panel? Have you tried it yourself??

Comment: @Niloo:: write your code within pageLoad(){ // } instead of $(document).ready(function () { // } to run it every-time the Page reloads or postbacks.

Comment: +1 Ok, its works for net 4+ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Avishek : Thanks, I have 3 script file. how do add this to pageload()

Comment: @Niloo : You dont have to re-add the script files after each partial/full postback. You just have to call the functions you need to run after each postback / write events inside pageLoad(){ // } in the js files. I will also edit the answer with an example.. :)

Answer (score 7):

You have to use following code after your update panel.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
pageRequestManager.add_endRequest(NewCharacterCount);
</script>
```

where `NewCharacterCount` is your javascript function name.

Read this article [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager endRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using UpdatePanel and you want to call a javascript function after content refresh in update panel, you can use below way to do it easily. In Page `body` tag , call a function `RefreshContent()`

```html
<body onload="RefreshContent()">

<script type="text/javascript">
  function RefreshContent()
  {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
  }

  function EndRequestHandler()
  {
    alert("Add your logic here" );
  }
</script>
```

Reference link
http://www.infoa2z.com/asp.net/how-to-call-javascript-function-after-an-updatepanel-asychronous-request-to-asp.net-page

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PageRequestManager client events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx). The sender parameter will contain the information you need. For example one could do this:

```
// Register event handler
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

/// Executed when all page content is refreshed, full page or async postback: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523.aspx
function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
    var isPostBack = sender.get_isInAsyncPostBack();
    if(!isPostBack) return;

    // PostBack logic here.
}
```