# Content Page with updatepanel not running javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a gridview,bootstrap modal that is inside update panel on a content page which references master page.

There are 3 columns in my gridview and a linkbutton.

When Linkbutton event is fired javascript should be fired which isn't.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(funct1);
```

I tried this but gives me sys undefined error in console.

Here's my code:

GridView -> View Button ->

```
var link = (Control)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)link.NamingContainer;
            Label LiD = (Label)row.FindControl("LabelID");
            id = Convert.ToInt32(LiD.Text);
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "funct1()", true)            
             MandateDetailusingId(id);
```

also tried with

```
//ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyFunction", "funct1()", true);
```

Here's my javacript :=

```
function funct1() {
            $('#<%=MandateView.ClientID%>').modal("toggle");
            return false;
        } // div id="MandateView"
```

How to up pop up modal ? everything is in updatepanel.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442175/5836671 for the correct way to use  `PageRequestManager`

Comment: @VDWWD I tried your method, it pops up modal on load. On button click it fires sys undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up solving with

```
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitialiseSettings);

function InitialiseSettings(){
    // replace your DOM Loaded settings here. 
    // If you already have document.ready event, 
    // just take the function part and replace here. 
    // Not with document.ready 
    $(element).slideUp(1000, method, callback});

    $(element).slideUp({
                   duration: 1000, 
                   easing: method, 
                   complete: callback});
}
```

event on page.

Thanks to this link.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038684/execute-javascript-after-a-partial-postback-of-an-updatepanel
```