# jquery calls are not fired in update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker, updatepanel

I have a update panel which updates each 1 minutes.

In side it, I have a two input files, when I click on each one, a datepicker function is called. 
I include these scripts for the datepicker

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"/>
```

Also, I have this script in my `head` tag

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#CldrFrom, #CldrTo").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

The datepicker works before the update panel updates the content. but after that, It is not working anymore.

what should I do please?

#### Note

I already have `function pageLoad(sender, args)` in one of my scripts but I don't think this could cause the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.Net UpdatePanel in Gridview Jquery DatePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341623/asp-net-updatepanel-in-gridview-jquery-datepicker)

Comment: Try running `$("#CldrFrom, #CldrTo").datepicker();` again after each update.

Comment: @Aristos it is not duplicated my friend, that is a gridview, which makes it a compltelely different

Comment: @user3432257 Is not the gridview the issue, but the code for the UpdatePanel. See my answer there, is exactly the same way as here.

Comment: @wrxsti where please? do you mean in the `pageload` function ?

Comment: yes in the pageload as the last thing you do within the function or as a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinitialise the date picker after each refresh in update pannel, Use this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoaded)
});

function PageLoaded(sender, args) {
    $("#CldrFrom, #CldrTo").datepicker();

}
```

Comment: let me try it and tell you the result

Comment: Yup that should do it.

Comment: Guys, it seems that even before the update panel works, my datepicker is not working. why please?

Comment: As I showed you. I am initalizing it in my script in my head tag. is this correct? it was working before I added the updatepanel

Comment: Try to put an alert in the PageLoaded() function  to check whether it is getting fired after each updation

Comment: I did that and I can see the alert each minute.

Comment: my function is `pageLoad`, but yours is `PageLoaded` . is it a typo please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () 
{
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoadedUserFunc)
});

function PageLoadedSUserFunc(sender, args) 
{
    $("#FromDate, #ToDate").datePicker();
}
//Select by Id method is used here.
```

Assuming that FromDate and ToDate are existing in the updatepanel which will get refreshed everytime whenever pageload happens.